# MDAPI Convert is producing unexpected results due to url encoded symbols in filenames

Tags: salesforcedx, force-cli

I am trying to convert existing source to a SFDX project using the mdapi:convert command, however existing source files contain urlencoded symbols.
EX:

`Pre_Review_and_or_Waiver__c-Pre-Review and%2For Waiver Layout - Lender User.layout`

is converted to a directory with dirname = "Pre_Review_and_or_Waiver__c-Pre-Review and" and file within that dir called "or Waiver Layout - Lender User.layout-meta.xml"

`Pre_Review_and_or_Waiver__c-Pre-Review and\or Waiver Layout - Lender User.layout-meta`

Another issue I have encountered is reports within folders are not able to be pushed. 
EX:
`\reports\My_Report_Folder\Data_Report.report-meta.xml`

Produces an invalid string due to the \D not being escaped correctly.

How can I solve these issues?